# How to setup nested ForEach Controller and send sub-request on JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have 3 types of request,

```
request 1: www.test.com/data
```

will return data in JSON Array

```
 request 2: www.test.com/img/{img_id}
```

{img_id} comes from items return by  request 1, and requst 2 will return an {uid}

```
 request 3: www.test.com/test/{uid}
```

I use jmeter to test this flow, now I was able to send request 1 and 
then use ForEach Controller to send some request 2, but I don't how to send request 3 according to the response of each request 2

I'm newbie to JMeter , Is anyone could help , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one more [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) nested in the previous one.
So your Test Plan structure will be looks like:

```
Thread Group  
    Request 1  
        RegExpExtractor 1  
    ForEach Controller 1  
        Request 2  
            RegExpExtractor 2
        ForEach Controller 2  
            Request 3
```

You may use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) with `-1` as a `Match No.` parameter to use it in ForEach Controller (from `RegExpExtractor 1` to `ForEach Controller 1` and from `RegExpExtractor 2` to `ForEach Controller 2`).

Check this [Test Plan](https://www.redline13.com/share/testplan/77406#testDetails-content) as an example.